# Transparency in UIPopoverController with iOS8 and table views

Tags: uitableview, ios8

I have a UITableView inside a UIPopover. On iOS7, the tableview would be semi-transparent but on iOS8 it doesn't appear to have any transparency.

If I insert a UICollectionView instead and set it's backgroundColor to clearColor then it is all nicely semi transparent etc. Obviously I've tried the same trick on the table view - but no cigar.

Anyone know why this is?

[image]
[image]

NB: The reason I noticed it was because in my app, I have a table view (in a popover) then when you select a row, it pushes in a collection  view - and the transition is horrific as it goes from opaque table view to semi transparent collection view.

Thanks.